# JavaSpringBoot error: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing :

Tags: spring-boot

Geting this error when having multible OneToMany relation in one entity class
When i try to create a StockPurcheas i get this error: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing :
Before i added the portfolioHistory it workt fine, but afther i added it, it stop working.
I have also tryd multible different cascade types. When i have cascade type ALl or PERSIST i can create a stockPurchases but it also creates a new portfolio, when i want to use a portfolio that allredy exists.

```
`@Entity
@Table(name = "portfolio")
public class Portfolio {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long pid;

    @OneToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "portfolio_pid")
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "portfoliohistory-portfolio")
    private Set<PortfolioHistory> portfolioHistories = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "portfolio_pid")
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "portfolio_stockpurchase")
    private Set<StockPurchase> stockPurchases = new HashSet<>();


    /**
     * Constructor for portfolio.
     * @param user the user you want to set that owns the portfolio.
     */
    public Portfolio(User user) {
        setUser(user);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor needed for JPA
     */
    public Portfolio() {}

    /**
     * Sets the user.
     * @param user the user yo want to set
     */
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    /**
     * Return user.
     * @return user.
     */
    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    /**
     * Returns portfolio id.
     * @return pid.
     */
    public Long getPid() {
        return this.pid;
    }

    public void setPid(Long pid) {
        pid = pid;
    }

    public Set<StockPurchase> getStockPurchases() {
        return stockPurchases;
    }

    public void setStockPurchases(Set<StockPurchase> stockPurchases) {
        this.stockPurchases = stockPurchases;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the portfolio is valid
     * @return boolean statement. True if portfolio is valid, false if not.
     */
    public boolean isValid() {
        return this.user != null;
    }


    public Set<PortfolioHistory> getPortfolioHistories() {
        return portfolioHistories;
    }

    public void setPortfolioHistories(Set<PortfolioHistory> portfolioHistories) {
        this.portfolioHistories = portfolioHistories;
    }
}
`



`/**
 * This class represent the Stock Purchase
 *
 * @author gruppe 9
 * @version 1.0
 */

@Entity
@Table(name = "stock_purchase")
public class StockPurchase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long spid;

    private Date date = new Date();

    private float price;

    private int quantity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "stock_id")
    @JsonBackReference(value = "stock_stockpurchase")
    private Stock stock;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "portfolio_id")
    @JsonBackReference(value = "portfolio_stockpurchase")
    private Portfolio portfolio;


    /**
     * Default constructor.
     * @param date the date you want to set.
     * @param price the price you want to set.
     * @param quantity the quantity of stock you want to set.
     * @param stock the type of stock you want to set.
     * @param portfolio the portfolio this purchase belong to.
     */
    public StockPurchase(Date date, float price, int quantity, Stock stock, Portfolio portfolio) {
        setDate(date);
        setPrice(price);
        setQuantity(quantity);
        setStock(stock);
        setPortfolio(portfolio);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor neede for JPA.
     */
    public StockPurchase() {

    }

    public Long getSpid() {
        return spid;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public Stock getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public Portfolio getPortfolio() {
        return portfolio;
    }

    public void setSpid(Long spid) {
        this.spid = spid;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public void setStock(Stock stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public void setPortfolio(Portfolio portfolio) {
        this.portfolio = portfolio;
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        return this.date != null && this.price > 0 && this.stock != null
                && this.portfolio != null && this.quantity > 0;
    }
}`

`
@Entity
@Table(name = "portfoliohistory")
public class PortfolioHistory {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long phid;
    private double price;
    private Date date;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "portfolio_pid")
    @JsonBackReference(value = "portfoliohistory-portfolio")
    private Portfolio portfolio;

    public PortfolioHistory(double price, Date date, Portfolio portfolio) {
        setPrice(price);
        setDate(date);
        setPortfolio(portfolio);
    }

    public PortfolioHistory() {}

    public Long getPhid() {
        return phid;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public Portfolio getPortfolio() {
        return portfolio;
    }

    public void setPhid(Long phid) {
        this.phid = phid;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setPortfolio(Portfolio portfolio) {
        this.portfolio = portfolio;
    }
}
`
```